# Traversing 'JSON Array of arrays' in python 'List of lists' format

Tags: javascript, json, nagios

For reasons I don't understand, the JSON format data I need to parse that comes out of a webservice isn't in nme value pairs.  'For simplicity and to reduce overhead' the returned JSON seems to be in a format that works with python eval but as far as I can see not with javascript (caveat, my javascript is very poor so I could be wrong - php etc, fine. js, not so much!)

So the data is returned as:

```
[[0, 'OK'],
 [['ITEM10314', ['ITEM10397']],
  ['ITEM10315', ['cornflower']],
  ['ITEM10397', ['ITEM10315']],
  ['ITEM10514', ['ITEM10397']],
  ['ITEM003', []],
  ['ITEM004', []],
  ['servertest', ['ITEM004', 'ITEM003']],
  ['serverroot', []]]]
```

(in case you are interested, it is a reply from a MKLiveStatus for Nagios LQL host query)

The first array is the status, then subsequent arrays consist of the host monitored in nagios and that host's parents (in an inner array).

Nice, isn't it.  But I need to get it into decent key/value pairs and there must be a better way than writing my own parser for this (not least because this is one data output but there are several more in similar formats).

I'm trying to keep this all in native js but if there is a jQuery easy way then I'm easily led to lazyness.  No need to worry about old browsers, I don't care, this project ends up using d3.js which won't work on old browsers anyway.

Any suggestions?  The depth in this case won't go below what it is here, so that at least is a known. However, I can't just flatten it, I need to know which parents a host has after this.

I have seen a few python-js links here but not arbitrary unknown sized lists in lists.

Comment: I think a custom parser is the only way to convert their custom multidimensional array into an an object

Comment: If it's not in JS object notation, it is not (by definition) JSON.

Comment: @rick - all JSON is JS, but not all JS is JSON. The code shown IS valid js.

Comment: You did not disprove what I just said. If you have an array of arrays, that in and of itself is not valid JSON. I didn't say anything about the validity of the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
var data = [
    [0, "OK"],
    [
        ["ITEM10314", ["ITEM10397"]],
        ["ITEM10315", ["cornflower"]],
        ["ITEM10397", ["ITEM10315"]],
        ["ITEM10514", ["ITEM10397"]],
        ["ITEM003", []],
        ["ITEM004", []],
        ["servertest", ["ITEM004", "ITEM003"]],
        ["serverroot", []]
    ]
];

function parse(array) {
    var object = {
            ok: 1
        };

    if (!Array.isArray(array) && array[0][0] !== 0 && array[0][1] !== "OK") {
        return object;
    }

    object.ok = 0;
    array[1].forEach(function (element) {
        object[element[0]] = element[1];
    });

    return object;
}

console.log(parse(data));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PVC2U/)

Comment: I can't get it to format as a comment, need the OP to update it in his question or someone with the right level of power.

Comment: I flagged it for a moderators help.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I don't consent to the edits, especially editing of my code sample.

Comment: I'm on a phone at the moment but ill update this as soon as a I get to my laptop later this morning (uk) - [edit just read it more carefully and saw the mod fixed it, thanks!]

Comment: Thanks, that does the job nicely.  If only people who said they outputted json actually did <sigh> thanks Xotic750, thanks all!